# How to get all the pixel data (RGB) of an image through c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, rgb, pixel, getpixel

From a JPG or PNG file, I want pixel data in the form of 2D array.
What is the procedure to do it OR which libraries can do that task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try openCV library. Here is it's [site](http://opencv.org) that you can download and install it.
Here is the code that does what you want:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Mat image = imread("C:/.../image1.jpg");
Vec3b buf;

for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
    {
        buf = image.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
        array_B[i][j] = buf[0];
        array_G[i][j] = buf[1];
        array_R[i][j] = buf[2];
    }

//imwrite("C:/.../image2.jpg",image3);
imshow("Image",image);
waitKey(0);
}
```